# Merging / grouping class instances

Tags: python, polymorphism, magic-methods, duck-typing

**So I have this task to practice Polymorphism and usage of abstract classes:**

> Create a class called Person. Upon initialization it will receive a
>   name (str) and a surname (str). Create another class called Group.
>   Upon initialization it should receive a name (str) and people (list of
>   Person instances). Implement the needed magic methods, so the test
>   code below works

**And the following test code:**

```
p0 = Person('Aliko', 'Dangote')
p1 = Person('Bill', 'Gates')
p2 = Person('Warren', 'Buffet')
p3 = Person('Elon', 'Musk')
p4 = p2 + p3

first_group = Group('__VIP__', [p0, p1, p2])
second_group = Group('Special', [p3, p4])
third_group = first_group + second_group

print(len(first_group))
print(second_group)
print(third_group[0])

for person in third_group:
    print(person)
```

**The output should be:**

```
3
Group Special with members Elon Musk, Warren Musk
Person 0: Aliko Dangote
Person 0: Aliko Dangote
Person 1: Bill Gates
Person 2: Warren Buffet
Person 3: Elon Musk
Person 4: Warren Musk
```

**So far I have basic knowledge about the magic methods and used few for comparison.
The code I came up with so far is as follows:**

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    #TODO
"""
Magic method that will merge the name and surname of 2 Person class  instances or combine the lists (with Person class instances) of Group class instances
"""

    def __repr__(self):
        pass


class Person(Base):
    def __init__(self, name: str, surname: str):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def __repr__(self):
        #TODO
        """Implement logic to get the idx of the Person class instance from the self.people list (some sort of duck
        typing?) that is called to be printed."""
        return f'Person {idx}: {self.name} {self.surname}'


class Group(Base):
    def __init__(self, name: str, people: list):
        self.name = name
        self.people = people

    def __repr__(self):
        people = [f'{p.name} {p.surname}' for p in self.people]
        return f'Group {self.name} with members {", ".join(people)}'
```

**Will be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: You need to override [`object.__add__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), [`object.__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) and [`object.__iadd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thank you. Ive red about these 3 and implemented them for the person merging. But what about group merging. I got it to merge the lists but what about the group name? and moreove does any of these can be used to get the desired idx mentioned in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement __len__ ,you can use  len(first_group) ,and __getitem__ for third_group[0],
here is the code:

```
class Person:
    idx = -1

    def __init__(self, name: str, surname: str):
        Person.idx += 1
        self.idx = Person.idx
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    def __repr__(self):
        # TODO
        """Implement logic to get the idx of the Person class instance from the self.people list (some sort of duck
        typing?) that is called to be printed."""
        return f'Person {self.idx}: {self.name} {self.surname}'

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Person):
            return Person(self.name, other.surname)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: {type(self)} and {type(other)}')


class Group:
    def __init__(self, name: str, people: list):
        self.name = name
        self.people = people

    def __repr__(self):
        people = [f'{p.name} {p.surname}' for p in self.people]
        return f'Group {self.name} with members {",".join(people)}'

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Group):
            return Group(self.name, self.people + other.people)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: {type(self)} and {type(other)}')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.people)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            return self.people[item]
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'need int but get {type(item)}')


p0 = Person('Aliko', 'Dangote')
p1 = Person('Bill', 'Gates')
p2 = Person('Warren', 'Buffet')
p3 = Person('Elon', 'Musk')
p4 = p2 + p3

first_group = Group('__VIP__', [p0, p1, p2])
second_group = Group('Special', [p3, p4])
third_group = first_group + second_group

print(len(first_group))
print(second_group)
print(third_group[0])

for person in third_group:
    print(person)
```

Comment: about the __getitem__ - it expects int as argument, but in the code below - for peron in third_group - person is a Person object. So from where does that int come from?

Comment: it's python magic ,for ... in ... will first try __iter__ method ,if class not implement it , __getitem__ will be used begin 0 until it raise StopIteration.

Comment: ok. One more thing - about the indices of Person objects. If we for example have third_group = second_group + first_group and then for person in third_group printed indices will be messed up - 3, 4, 0, 1, 2. So is there some python vodoo method that can take the index of the Person object in the end list?

Comment: use sorted() : you can use it at Group init method : self.people=sorted(people,key=lambda p:p.idx)

Comment: enumerate for extra index :
for index,person in enumerate(third_group,start=0):
    print(index ,person)